# Getting location information of Android phones connected to a wifi access point

Tags: android, geolocation, wifi, signal-strength

I am trying to get the location information of Android phones connected to a particular wifi access point/hotspot which is another Android device. I know how to obtain location information for a particular Android device using the Location API as well as the signal strength information of the access points in vicinity. Actually I am trying to send the location information of all the nodes connected to the hotspot. For that maybe I need to open different sockets. After that based on that information I have make some decisions. Can anyone give me a good approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get location direction from WiFi hotspot (actually WiFi spot itself doesn't know where it's located).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_Wireless
there are databases which contains mapping between WiFi hotspot MAC address and locations. So, your application should get info about WiFi hotspot and after go to one of this databases.

To know more about that u can refer this one http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html